# MongoDB Query with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I was working in this query that you can see below and pythons IDE gives me a syntax error in "$group"´s line.The error is an "invalid syntax string" but I can not find where the problem is.

```
ID="01"
yearInicial="2018"
monthInicial="02"
dayInicial="11"
yearFinal="2018"
monthFinal="06"
dayFinal="22"
total=0
totalDias=0 

result=list(db.alojamientos.aggregate( [ {'$match': { '$and': [ {"location.thcod":ID}, { "prices.year": { '$gte': yearInicial } },
                            { "prices.year": { '$lte': yearFinal } }, {"prices.months.month": { '$gte': monthInicial } },
                             { "prices.months.month": { '$lte': monthFinal } }, { "prices.months.days.day": { '$gte': dayInicial } },
                              { "prices.months.days.day": { '$lte': dayFinal } }]}}, 

                                  {'$unwind':"$prices"},
                                  {'$unwind':"$prices.months"},
                                  {'$unwind':"$prices.months.days"},
                                  {'$unwind':"$prices.months.days.csvs"},
                                  {'$unwind':"$prices.months.days.csvs.price"},
                                  {'$group':{'_id':{ID, 'day':"$prices.months.days.day",'month': "$prices.months.month",'year':"$prices.year"},total:{'$sum':"$prices.months.days.csvs.price.price"}, count: { '$sum': 1 }

}}]))
```

Thanks you in advance

Comment: `:{ID, 'day':` is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the 3rd `{` in this line `{'$group':{'_id':{ID, ...`.
And it should looks like `{'$group':{'_id':ID, ...`